# Powershell script - manage empty parameters

Tags: powershell

Am automating youtubeDl tasks with Powershell via some functions in profile.ps1
This function accepts different parameters - if some are set, i'll setup additional config to youtube-dl executable.

For instance, executing `ytDl https://vimeo.com/1548390390` would result in executing `.\youtube-dl.exe  https://vimeo.com/1548390390`.
When executing `ytDl https://vimeo.com/1548390390 3458F89` would lead to
`.\youtube-dl.exe  https://vimeo.com/1548390390 --video-password 3458F89`

Am able to do what i want working script is not "beautiful"/"clean". I pasted below the two versions.

Can anyone of you help me - explain me why it's not behaving as expected ?
Thanks a lot !

```
function ytDl_Working_But_NotBeautiful {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)][string]$password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)][string]$youtubeDlPath = "C:\APPS\"
    )
        Write-Host "URL = $url || Password = $password"
        
        cd $youtubeDlPath
        
        if ($password.Length -gt 0) {
            Write-Host "Password set - adding video-password parameter"
            .\youtube-dl.exe $url --video-password $password
        }
        else{
            .\youtube-dl.exe $url
        }
}

function ytDl_NotWorking {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)][string]$password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)][string]$youtubeDlPath = "C:\APPS\"
    )
        Write-Host "URL = $url || Password = $password"
        
        $fullParams = $url
        if ($password.Length -gt 0) {
            Write-Host "Password set - adding video-password parameter"
            $fullParams = "$url --video-password $password"
        }
        Write-Host ".\youtube-dl.exe $fullParams"
        
        .\youtube-dl.exe $fullParams
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what exactly you are expecting and how these functions defy your expectations.

Comment: Updated description, thanks for highlighting it !

Comment: And what is it that's "not working"?

Comment: When i launch ytDl with some parameters, it works (sets properly the extra parameter)
```ytDl https://vimeo.com/473689210 2345no


[vimeo] 473689210: Downloading webpage
[vimeo] 473689210: Extracting information
[vimeo] 473689210: Verifying the password

```

When launching ytDl2 with same param; it fails
```ytDl2 https://vimeo.com/473689210 2345no
Password set - adding video-password parameter
[vimeo:user] 473689210 --video-password 2345no: Downloading page 1
```
Which means parameters are not properly set. 
Thus this question  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable number of arguments to an executable without having to write many nested `if/else` statements, take advantage of [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)!

```bsh
function Save-OnlineVideo
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)][string]$password,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)][string]$youtubeDlPath = "C:\APPS\"
    )

    # Create array to hold the arguments
    $fullParams = @($url)

    if ($password.Length -gt 0) {
        # Add any additional arguments to the array
        $fullParams += "--video-password","$password"
    }

    # prepend variable name with @ instead of $ to make powershell splat them
    .\youtube-dl.exe @fullParams
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working.
```Usage: youtube-dl.exe [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl.exe: error: no such option: --video-password PASSWORD```

My understanding is that we are setting one parameter ( --video-password PASSWORD) whilst we should be setting a -- --video-password parameter which value is PASSWORD.

Comment: @FranckDeny Updated the answer

Comment: BTW - thanks to your splatting explanation, i now understand many scripts i've seen before :)